# How to add primary key and foreign key to a BigQuery?

Tags: database, google-bigquery, create-table

I am trying to learn bigquery but I noticed I cannot add Primary key or Foreign Keys at all.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE db.VENDOR 
(
    V_CODE      INT64,
    V_NAME      String NOT NULL,
    V_CONTACT   String NOT NULL,
    V_AREACODE  String NOT NULL,
    V_PHONE     String NOT NULL,
    V_STATE     String NOT NULL,
    V_ORDER     String NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(V_Code)
);

CREATE TABLE db.PRODUCT 
(
    P_CODE     string Not Null,
    P_DESCRIPT string NOT NULL,
    P_INDATE   DATETIME NOT NULL,
    P_QOH      int64 NOT NULL,
    P_MIN      int64 NOT NULL,
    P_PRICE    NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    P_DISCOUNT NUMERIC NOT NULL,
    V_CODE     int64,

    CONSTRAINT PRODUCT_V_CODE_FK 
        FOREIGN KEY (V_CODE) REFERENCES VENDOR (V_CODE)
);
```

When I use primary key, I get an error:

> Primary Key is not supported

and for the foreign key I get:

> Table name "VENDOR" missing dataset while no default dataset is set in the request

Is there anyway to use PK or FK in BigQuery? if yes, How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out the docs for [Primary keys](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_add_primary_key_statement) and [Foreign keys](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_add_constraint_statement)

The following example adds the primary key constraint of x and y to the pk_table table:

```
ALTER TABLE pk_table ADD PRIMARY KEY (x,y) NOT ENFORCED;
```

The following example adds the my_fk_name foreign key constraint to the fk_table table. This example depends on an existing table, pk_table.

```
ALTER TABLE fk_table
ADD CONSTRAINT my_fk_name FOREIGN KEY (u, v)
REFERENCES pk_table(x, y) NOT ENFORCED;
```

Note, key constraints are not enforced, so they will not prevent duplicates. They are used primarily to help optimizer - [Why create Primary Keys and Foreign Keys?](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/data-analytics/join-optimizations-with-bigquery-primary-and-foreign-keys)

Comment: 2 people have answered that primary keys are added. But no one has mentioned that they don't work: as of 2023-04-25, you can't create a PK without NOT ENFORCED clause. And you CAN insert records with duplicated PKs, so BigQuery is not doing any uniqueness checks for you. I don't know what is the point of presenting such "feature" that does not work. "Good job", Google.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @AnatolyAlekseev. Adding a feature which doesn't comply it's main functionality is really surprising for me!

Answer (score 4):

Now bigquery has added support to add PRIMARY,FOREIGN key as constraint to tables.
you can check below documentation :

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_add_constraint_statement